# How to pass " (double quote) as a delimiter value in Spring context XML file

Tags: spring

I am reading a CSV file that has values in between the quotes. E.g.: `"1234,abcd,ijkl"`.
I have added `,` as delimiter value in Spring context file as:
`property name="delimiter" value=","`. Through this I can remove the `,` in the given example.

I want to remove `"` (quotes at the start and end). I tried option like `property name="delimiter" value="\""` but it is not working.

Please suggest me how to pass quotes as a delimiter value in Spring context XML file.

Answer (score 0):

XML has special escaping rules. `\` is a normal character in XML without any special features. Try `value="&quot;"` or `value="&#34;"`

Comment: Thanks. One Question here, how can I pass both comma and quote in a single property . I mean property name="delimiter" value=",&quot". Is this right?

Comment: @user3242119: From an XML point of view, yes. This will simply pass `,"` to the bean. It doesn't magically make the bean support multiple delimiter characters :-)